# Stop volume change noise when Sennheiser Bluetooth headphones connected on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, system-sounds

When my Sennheiser HD 4.50 BTNC Bluetooth headphones are connected to my Windows 10 PC - changing the volume makes a beeping noise.

This is the case whether I press the volume button on the headphones, using the mouse scroll wheel or the keyboard volume buttons.

I've tried going to Windows sound and selected 'No Sound' (disabling all system sounds), clicked Apply, and it still makes the sound when changing volume if the Bluetooth headphones are connected. When I disconnect the headphones - the noise no longer happens (if using the keyboard or mouse to change volume).

How do I disable this sound?

**Update**

This happens whatever device they are connected to - it's a design flaw in the headphones themselves.

Thanks.